# Prove that it is possible to place $n$ nonattcking rooks

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Consider an $n$-by-$n$ board in which there is a nonnegative number
>   $a_{ij}$ in the square in row $i$ and column $j$, ($1\leq i,j \leq
>  n$). Assume that the sum of the numbers in each row and in each column
>   equals $1$. Prove that it is possible to place $n$ nonattacking rooks
>   on the board at positions occupied by positive numbers.

My attempt:

Consider the sets $S_i = \{ j : a_{ij} \neq 0\}$, $1\leq i \leq n$. It suffices to show $\Gamma=(S_1, \cdots, S_n)$ satisfies the Marriage Condition (MC). It would then follow from Hall's theorem that $\Gamma$ has an SDR and we are done.

Now, suppose (MC) does not hold. There exists some integer $l$, $1<l\leq n$, such that the union of $l$ sets contains less than $l$ distinct elements. In particular, denote these $l$ sets by $S_{k_1}, \cdots, S_{k_l}$.

I am stuck here. The only thing I can think of is that the sum of all elements in these $l$ sets is $l$ since the sum of each row is $1$. How can I make use of the column sum? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you mean to assume there is a set of $l$ rows $R \subseteq \{1, ..., N\}$ such that $\cup_{i \in R} S_i$ contains less than $l$ columns.  And I agree $\sum_{i \in R} \sum_{j \in S_i} a_{ij} = l$.   If it helps, you can define the set of columns as $C = \cup_{i \in R} S_i$.  So $|C|<|R|=l$. You just need to reach a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a completely different, constructive, method.

I will define four operations on a doubly stochastic matrix.

- $R_{ij}$, which swaps rows $i, j$;
- $C_{ij}$, which swaps columns $i,j$;
- $S_{(i_1, j_1), (i_2, j_2)}$ which does the following.

> Given any 2x2 submatrix $$\begin{matrix}
>   a & b \\
>   c & d 
>  \end{matrix}$$
>
> we may replace it by $$\begin{matrix}
>   0 & a+b \\
>   a+c & d-a
>  \end{matrix}$$
>
> as long as $d \geq a$. This keeps a doubly stochastic matrix doubly stochastic.

- $T_{(i_1, j_1), (i_2, j_2)}$, which does the following.

> Given any 2x2 submatrix $$\begin{matrix}
>   a & b \\
>   c & d 
>  \end{matrix}$$
>   we may replace it by $$\begin{matrix}
>   a-d & b+d \\
>   c+d & 0
>  \end{matrix}$$
>
> as long as $a \geq d$. This keeps a doubly stochastic matrix doubly stochastic.

Given any valid rook placement for $C_{ij}(M)$, we easily obtain a valid rook placement for $M$ by just moving the rooks with the columns; likewise for $R_{ij}(M)$.

I claim that given any valid rook placement for $S_{(i_1, j_1), (i_2, j_2)}(M)$, we can also produce a valid rook placement for $M$, as follows. The rook positions in $M$ will be the same as those in $S(M)$, except possibly for the four positions we altered. The rooks in those four positions are as follows:

- There can't be a rook in the top-left ($0$) position in $S(M)$, because that entry is zero in $S(M)$.
- If there is a rook in the top-right position ($a+b$) in $S(M)$ and a rook in the bottom-left position $(a+c)$ in $S(M)$, then we can keep the rook positions the same in $M$. Indeed, $a+c \not = 0$ and $a+b \not = 0$, so $b, c \not = 0$, so they are valid rook placements.
- If there is a rook in the top-right position but none in the bottom-left position in $S(M)$, then we can keep the rook positions the same in $M$, likewise.
- If there is a rook in the bottom-left position but not in the top-right position in $S(M)$, then we can keep the rook positions the same in $M$, likewise.
- If there is a rook in the bottom-right position in $S(M)$, then $d-a \not = 0$ so $d \not = 0$ and so we can keep the rook positions the same.
- Otherwise there are no rooks in the bits of $S(M)$ which differ from $M$, so we can just keep the rook positions the same.

So actually what we've just proved is that given a valid rook placement in $S(M)$, the same rook placement works in $M$.

The same works with $T(M)$.

Therefore, it is enough to show that we can do some combinations of $C, R, S, T$ to get a matrix in which we can place the rooks.

Finally, I claim that if we do combinations of $C, R, S, T$ in the right order, we can make it so that the top row of the matrix is all zeros apart from a 1 in the top-right. Then we can place that rook and we're done by induction.

Define a reduction procedure:

> Let $a$ be the first entry in the lexicographic order $M_{1,1}, M_{1,2}, \dots, M_{1, n}$. If $a = 0$, move to the next entry. Otherwise, two cases:
>
> - there is some entry $d$ below and to the right of $a$ which has $d \geq a$; in this case, we can perform $S$ to set $a=0$, and move on to the next entry.
> - there is no entry $d$ below and to the right of $a$ which has $d \geq a$. If all those entries are $0$, then we're actually done, because the next entry along must be $1$, so wlog we can do $T$ using some entry below and to the right of $a$, to reduce $a$. Then repeat using $a$ again.

When this reduction terminates, the top row is all zeros apart from one 1 in the rightmost entry, so we're done. (It does terminate: at each stage, either we set the element to zero and move on to the right, or we set some element below-and-right of our current one to zero and repeat, so we're reducing the number of nonzero entries below-and-right of the current one each time.)

Answer (score 0):

After some more thinking with the hints given, I have come up with a simple solution. So I decided to post it as an answer here.

---

Consider the sets $S_i=\{j:a_{ij}\neq 0\}$, $1 \leq i \leq n$. It suffices to show $\Gamma=(S_1, \cdots, S_n)$ satisfies the Marriage Condition (MC). It would then follow from Hall's theorem that $\Gamma$ has an SDR and we are done.

Now, suppose (MC) does not hold. There exists some integer $l$, $1 \leq l \leq n$, such that the union of these $l$ rows contains less than $l$ non-zero columns, say $m<l$ columns. Clearly, the sum of the entries in these $l$ rows is $l$. Now, consider these $m$ non-zero columns. Since there are $m$ columns, the sum of all these entries should  be at most $m$. But then contraction arrives as we add up the same number of entries in two different ways (row sum and column sum) and obtain two different values ($l$ and $m<l$ respectively). Hence, (MC) must hold and the result follows.